# Condicional SI con Excel

Tags: excel, microsoft-office

Si la celda esta vacía, que copie el valor anterior, de lo contrario que conserve el valor actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
K29= OF.ESP. CHALHUANCA

SI(K30="",K29,K30)
```

La actual formula no me funciona, me arroja valor 0 en todas, en que podría estar fallando?

**UPDATE**

Estoy aplicando la formula en la celda de abajo, con la recomendación de una respuesta pero me sigue saliendo el 0, estoy aplicandolo correctamente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: Hola amigo creo que deberias de usar algo como =SI(ESBLANCO(K30);K29,K30)

Comment: Amigo creo que tu problema esta en que tu estas haciendo referencia a la celda que contiene la formula, por ejemplo la formula "=SI(ESBLANCO(K30);K29,K30)" si funciona pero esta formula no debes colocarla en la celda K30, por esa razon te da 0, ya que la celda no esta vacia contiene una formula y si valor al tener formula es 0

Comment: @MichaelTorrez si amigo lo se , pero como podría solucionarlo , si los resultados los necesito en esas casillas , tengo miles de datos necesito un proceso automático

Comment: Estimado, si nos proporsiona un poco mas de datos y sobre las celdas que estas trabajando... podriamos facilitarte una macros que te solucione el problema, por que la verdad estoy algo confundido con tu logica para aplicar la formula, si haces referencia a la celda que tiene la formula? esta siempre estara con valor 0

Comment: @MichaelTorrez gracias amigo , en un principio de la pregunta , facilite un ejemplo ,con la misma estructura que tengo , y en la parte del 'update' especifico aun mas , si talves no alcanza con esto , me podrías indicar q mas podría incluir , gracias

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que estás usando referencias circulares, y eso es **muy problemático y muy poco recomendable**.

> **[Referencias circulares](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/quitar-o-permitir-una-referencia-circular-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123)**

En una celda, en principio, solamente puede haber una de 3 opciones:

1. Una **constante**, es decir, un valor escrito a mano
2. Una **fórmula** que devuelve un valor
3. Que la **celda esté vacía**, es decir, un valor nulo.

Cabe destacar que si una fórmula devuelve un valor nulo, la celda **no está vacía** porque en realidad tiene una fórmula.

Dicho esto, entiendo que tú lo que quieres es una fórmula que te permita crear listas rápidamente, para rellenar los huecos en blanco. En la propia columna **no es posible hacerlo con fórmulas de excel comunes** (con macros sí). Pero sí que puedes hacerlo en una columna auxiliar, sacas la lista, y luego copias y pegas encima de la original, y borras la columna que usaste como ayuda.

Un ejemplo. Tú tienes lo que he puesto en la columna A, y quieres llegar a lo que hay en la B, pero en la columna A.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fórmula que he usado en la columna B es:

`=SI(A2="";B1;A2)`

Luego, **selecciono todo lo que hay en la columna B--> Copiar--->Pegar Valores**. Así transformamos todo en constantes.

Luego borro la columna A para que lo que tengo en la B se convierta en la A. Lista conseguida :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

La condicion de excel le falta la funcion `ESBLANCO()` que pregunta si el contenido de la celda esta vacio, de ser cierto devuelve **TRUE**, en caso contrario **FALSE**.

```
=SI(ESBLANCO(A2);A1;A2)
```

Entonces aqui ahora se evalua si la celda A2 esta en blanco devolvera el valor de A1 en caso contrario muestra A2

Ejemplo ejecutandose donde: **celda A2 esta en blanco y A1 tiene contenido:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo ejecutandose donde: **celda A2 tiene contenido y A1 tiene contenido:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Amigo , gracias por tu respuesta , actualice mi pregunta, con tu recomendacion pero me sigue saliendo 0

Comment: El valor 0 sale cuando niguno de los  valores tiene contenido, otra cosa que tambien debes hacer es colocar la posicion de las celdas de tu ejercicio, yo use A1 y A2 como ejemplo